# Does dynamoDB charge for throttled requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Whenever dynamoDB throws the ProvisionedThroughputExceededException, does DynamoDB still charge us for the request sent to it.

Update :

1. we use both the schemes, provisioned + auto scaling and OnDemand for our DDB tables.
2. I am trying to understand if DDB will still consider WCU/RCU consumed for throttled requests which resulted in ProvisionedThroughputExceededException
3. DynamoDB in their definition of WCU and RCU states that every API call to DDB is considered as write/read request. (https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/) Does it mean that even failed API calls ( Internal Error 500, ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) will be charged ?

Comment: What about other exceptions? Does one rule apply for all (charge or no charge)?

Comment: Related: for ConditionalCheckFailedException, "If a ConditionExpression evaluates to false during a conditional write, DynamoDB still consumes write capacity from the table"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the response I got from AWS support. They don't charge when the request to DDB gets throttled.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Provisioned Capacity**, there is no charge for the individual requests. Rather, you pay for a particular *capacity* of requests.

If you are using **On-Demand Capacity**, requests are charged at `$1.4231 per million write request units` and `$0.285 per million read request units`. So, unless you are receiving millions of `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` errors, it wouldn't have much of an impact on your bill.

Comment: In one use case I am using provisioned with auto scaling and in other we do use on-demand.

Comment: Our tables do get millions of throttles because of spiky traffic. What I am trying to understand is if DDB treats the throttled request same as successful request while calculating the cost. so if let's for <1KB payload, is  1WCU consumed for even throttled request and thus added into the bill

Comment: I assume that the cost is different per region too